# getline не дает писать в консоль

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string valid_pass = "qwerty123";
    string user_pass;
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    getline(cin, user_pass);
    if (user_pass == valid_pass) {
        cout << "Доступ разрешен." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Неверный пароль!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

в консоли появляется Введите пароль: , а писать в неё не получается

Comment: У меня получается. Что я делаю  не так?...

Comment: Все же работает.

Comment: @Miracle- значит беда в VS code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string valid_pass = "qwerty123";
    string user_pass;

    cout << "Введите пароль: " << endl;

    cin >> user_pass; //тут изменил. Работает в Линуксе.

    if (user_pass == valid_pass) {
    cout << "Доступ разрешен." << endl;
    } else {
    cout << "Неверный пароль!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю почему, но добавление cin.get() решило проблему